# How to combine a parent and a dependent child observable

Tags: rxjs

There is a continuous stream of event objects which doesn't complete. Each event has bands. By subscribing to events you get an event with several properties, among these a property "bands" which stores an array of bandIds. With these ids you can get each band. (The stream of bands is continuous as well.)

**Problem:** In the end you'd not only like to have bands, but a complete event object with bandIds and the complete band objects.

```js
    // This is what I could come up with myself, but it seems pretty ugly.

    getEvents().pipe(
        switchMap(event => {
            const band$Array = event.bands.map(bandId => getBand(bandId));
            return combineLatest(of(event), ...band$Array);
        })),
        map(combined => {
            const newEvent = combined[0];
            combined.forEach((x, i) => {
                if (i === 0) return;

                newEvent.bands = {...newEvent.bands, ...x};
            })
        })
    )
```

**Question:** Please help me find a cleaner way to do this (and I'm not even sure if my attempt produces the intended result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ACCEPTED ANSWER**

```js
getEvents().pipe(
    switchMap(event => {
        const band$Array = event.bands.map(bandId => getBand(bandId));
        return combineLatest(band$Array).pipe(
          map(bandArray => ({bandArray, event}))
        );
    })
)
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You may want to try something along these lines

```js
getEvents().pipe(
    switchMap(event => {
        const band$Array = event.bands.map(bandId => getBand(bandId));
        return forkJoin(band$Array).pipe(
          map(bandArray => ({bandArray, event}))
        );
    })
)
```

The Observable returned by this transformation emits an object with 2 properties: `bandArray` holding the array of bands retrieved with the `getBand` service and `event` which is the object emitted by the Observable returned by  `getEvents`.

Consider also that you are using `switchMap`, which means that as soon as the Observable returned by `getEvents` emits you are going to switch to the last emission and complete anything which may be on fly at the moment. In other words you can loose some events if the time required to exectue the `forkJoin` is longer than the time from one emission and the other of `getEvents`.

If you do not want to loose anything, than you better use `mergeMap` rather than `switchMap`.

**UPDATED ANSWER - The Band Observable does not complete**

In this case I understand that `getBand(bandId)` returns an Observable which emits first when the back end is queried the first time and then when the band data in the back end changes.
If this is true, then you can consider something like this

```js
getEvents().pipe(
    switchMap(event => {
        return from(event.bands).pipe(
           switchMap(bandId => getBand(bandId)).pipe(
              map(bandData => ({event, bandData}))
           )
        );
    })
)
```

This transformation produces an Observable which emits either any time a new event occurs or any time the data of a band changes.

Comment: You made me aware of a missing detail in my question:
Neither the stream of events nor the bands completes; both are persistent and receive continuous updates.

Comment: Then which is the meaning of the array of bandIds you receive with the event object?

Comment: You need the array of ids to know which bands are linked to a specific event. A band might still get an update which doesn't have an effect on its associated event. Example: The band members might change.

Comment: I think by replacing `forkJoin` with `combineLatest` your first suggestion is pretty much what I'm looking for.